# Undoing changes done to World Map shapefile in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, basemap, undo-redo

I realized that by typing *"world"* in the coordinate display at the bottom and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> there'll be a new world shapefile layer generated.

[image: input]

I edited the shapefile manually without knowing that is the same map used in displaying region for setting CRS. Any solution to revert the edited shapefile into the original map?

[image: the distorted map]

Comment: It's not a shapefile. It's a geopackage feature layer. Download https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/resources/data/world_map.gpkg and overwrite the existing world_map.gpkg in QGIS dir/resources/data

Comment: Sounds like an answer @user2856 - feel free to post as one.

Comment: That's strange: the map is in the installation folder, so normally, you should not be able to just edit this file. In my case, when I load this map as polygon layer, I'm not even able to toggled editing mode - I first have to export the file to another destination. So probably someting with writing permissions on your installation folder is not OK, what could probably cause some security issues.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a shapefile. It's a geopackage feature layer. Download [github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/resources/data/world_map.gpkg](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/resources/data/world_map.gpkg) and overwrite the existing world_map.gpkg in QGIS dir/resources/data.

I'm not sure why you were able to edit it. You may have installed QGIS in a user-writable location.

Comment: Were my edits irrelevant? :)